# Problem with the booking calendar in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem with the booking calendar on my app in Laravel 8. Please i really need help :(

After pressing the 'book' button, an error pops up:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [FrontendController] does not exist.
http://localhost/testowa7/public/makeReservation/26/5

Room blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('makeReservation',['room_id'=>$room->id,'city_id'=>$room->object->city->id]) }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dayin">Przyjazd</label>
                        <input required name="dayin" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="dayin" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dayout">Wyjazd</label>
                        <input required name="dayout" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="dayout" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rezerwuj</button>
                    <p class="text-danger">{{ Session::get('reservationMsg') }}</p>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
```

Route:

```
 Route::post('/makeReservation/{room_id}/{city_id}','FrontendController@makeReservation')->name('makeReservation');
```

FrontendController:

```
public function makeReservation($room_id, $city_id, Request $request)
    {

      $avaiable = $this->fG->checkAvaiableReservations($room_id,$request);

      if(!$avaiable)
      {
          if(!$request->ajax())  // niepotrzebne bez apki
          {
            $request->session()->flash('reservationMsg',_('No vanancies'));
            return redirect()->route('room',['id'=>$room_id,'#reservation']);
          }

          return response()->json(['reservation'=>false]);  //niepotrzebne bez apki

      }
      else
      {
        $reservation = $this->fG->makeReservation($room_id,$city_id,$request);

        if(!$request->ajax())
        return redirect()->route('adminHome');
        else
        return response()->json(['reservation'=>$reservation]);

      }
      
    }
```

FrontendRepository:

```
 public function makeReservation($room_id, $city_id, $request)
  {
    return Reservation::create([

      'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
      'city_id' => $city_id,
      'room_id' => $room_id,
      'status' => 0,
      'dayin' => $request->input('dayin'),
      'dayout' => $request->input('dayout'),

    ]);
  }
```

FrontendGateway:

```
public function checkAvaiableReservations($room_id,$request)
  {
    $reservations = $this->fR->getReservationsByRoomId($room_id);

    $avaiable = true;

    foreach($reservations as $reservation)
    {
        if( $request->input('dayin') >= $reservation->day_in
          && $request->input('dayin') <= $reservation->day_out
        )
        {
          $avaiable =false;break;
        }
        elseif( $request->input('dayout') >= $reservation->day_in
          && $request->input('dayout') <= $reservation->day_out
        )
        {
          $avaiable =false;break;
        }
        if( $request->input('dayin') >= $reservation->day_in
          && $request->input('dayout') <= $reservation->day_out
        )
        {
          $avaiable =false;break;
        }
    }


    return $avaiable;

  }


  public function makeReservation($room_id, $city_id, $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'dayin' => "required|string",
      'dayout' => "required|string",
    ]);

    return $this->fR->makeReservation($room_id, $city_id, $request);
  }
```

Comment: Probably you didn't import ``FrontendController`` inside your route file. Also the url http://localhost/testowa7/public/makeReservation/26/5 looks strange. How did you run it? Try ``php artisan serve`` should send request to ``http://localhost:8000/makeReservation/26/5``

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 run with artisan serve. There are 15 routes in my web.php file and they all contain a frontendcontroller. All others work properly only on this route there is a problem. I wrote 'use App \ Http \ Controllers \ FrontendController;' it didn't work, I also tried 'use App \ Http \ Controllers' and still nothing. What else could it be? apart from the error from the question below, there is also:

Comment: Illuminate\Container\Container::build
C:\xampp\htdocs\testowa7\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879

Comment: try {

            $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

        } catch (ReflectionException $e) {

          879//  throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);

        }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `FrontendController` class namespace is imported into your `web.php` file.

Comment: there are 15 routes in my web.php file and they all contain a frontendcontroller. All others work properly only on this route there is a problem. I wrote 'use App \ Http \ Controllers \ FrontendController;' it didn't work, I also tried 'use App \ Http \ Controllers' and still nothing.

My entire routing file:

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController;
Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@index')->name('home');
Route::get(trans('routes.object').'/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@object')->name('object');
Route::get(trans('routes.article'),'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@article')->name('article');
Route::post(trans('routes.roomsearch'),'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@roomsearch')->name('roomSearch');

Comment: Route::get(trans('routes.room').'/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@room')->name('room');
Route::get(trans('routes.person').'/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@person')->name('person');

Route::get('/searchCities', 'FrontendController@searchCities');
Route::get('/ajaxGetRoomReservations/{id}', 'FrontendController@ajaxGetRoomReservations');

Route::get('/like/{likeable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@like')->name('like');
Route::get('/unlike/{likeable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@unlike')->name('unlike');

Comment: Route::post('/addComment/{commentable_id}/{type}','FrontendController@addComment')->name('addComment');
Route::post('/makeReservation/{room_id}/{city_id}','FrontendController@makeReservation')->name('makeReservation');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){    // middleware to filtr co sprawdza w auth czy jest zalogowany

    Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@index')->name('adminHome');
    Route::get(trans('routes.myobjects'),'App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@myobjects')->name('myObjects');

Comment: Route::get(trans('routes.saveobject'),'App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@saveobject')->name('saveObject');
    Route::get(trans('routes.profile'),'App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@profile')->name('profile');
    Route::get(trans('routes.saveroom'),'App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@saveroom')->name('saveRoom');
    Route::get(trans('routes.cities'),'App\Http\Controllers\BackendController@cities')->name('cities.index');
});

Auth::routes();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your FrontendController is imported correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).